# Batch file read from text file and concatenation with error: 'input line is too long'

Tags: batch-file, concatenation, file-read

I'm trying to read from txt file and concat rows in batch file. I encountered an unexpected error. Is there a way to bypass this error ?

**Batch File:**

```
@ECHO OFF 
TITLE Test File
ECHO Long Text Concat Test...

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set count=1
set tables=
for /f "tokens=*" %%s in (TablesForTest.txt) do (  
  set tables=!tables! /p:TableData=%%s

  set /a count += 1
)
endlocal && set count=%count% && set tables=%tables%

echo count      : %count%
echo tables     : %tables%

PAUSE
EXIT
```

**Output**

```
The input line is too long.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

**Text File Content**

```
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
[dbo].[Long_Table_Name]
```

Comment: cmd.exe has limits to the number of characters in a line, and importantly there are also limits to the number of characters which can be held in the variables environment. The 'bypass' for this would be to try to use or incorporate Windows PowerShell scripting for this task.

Comment: @Compo I tried it in powershell, the same error came up

Comment: serefbilge, you did not mention that at all in your question, or imply it in any way. I'm not currently capable of mind reading. What I would therefore advise, is that you [edit] your question title, body, and tags, in order that PowerShell specific membership can help you with your PowerShell issue.

Comment: @Compo I tried powershell after your advise, not before.

Comment: In `cmd.exe`, lines are limited to about 8190 bytes/characters, and so are environment variables (including their name and the `=`-sign, since they are stored like `VAR=Value` each)…

Answer (score 0):

You could use pseudo arrays, one per table instead of trying to build one big variable.

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%s in (TablesForTest.txt) do (  
  set "table[!count!]=/p:TableData=%%s"
  set /a count+=1
)

echo count      : %count%
echo tables     :
for /L %%n in (0 0 !count!) DO (
   echo !table[%%n]!
)
endlocal
```